# Dynamically generated input box resize and refresh position and size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form, inside that form is a button and an input field, I would like it that when someone clicks on the button "ADD MORE FIELDS" that there will be a new dynamically generated input box. I tried using [posted code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kddfx86d/) and this works but i need to get like in this picture:

[image]

So i need to get the input fields positioned like in this picture: 
- if one box is added in row then it gets width: 200px; 
- if two boxes are added in a row, the boxes get a width of: 100px
- if you look at the picture on the right; I need it to be possible to remove a box by clicking it, then when a box is removed. I'd like all the boxes to be aligned again into the same position (here box 3 is removed, 4 takes it's place, 6 becomes smaller and 5 moves to the left.).

I tried using the code below on jsfiddle but i think i need some css and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  })
});
```

~Thanks

Comment: Please don't ignore the warning box that states fiddle links should be accompanied by code in the question

Comment: So what constitutes a “row”? And when 3 is removed, that means 4 automatically switches to another row? By what _logic_ does 4 move up, instead of just staying in its current row together with 5?

Comment: A row is like in table (one horizontally line that holds one long box or two small boxes). Yes when 3 is removed it need to automatically switch to another row and move from next row (currently 4) to position 3. I im building form witch have dynamic adding input boxes when clicking on categories and then adding a new box or removing selected box..so if i when i deleted item3 leave empty place..that looks ugly on form and is not professional. So i need to fill place of removed 3 with box from 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: https://jsfiddle.net/6b24z4j7/4/

So basicly you needed to apply some nth-child css logic to maintain view order of inputs. I made little changes to jQuery, but it still maintain your logic. In fiddle example I made placeholder attribute to showcase how things work (you can remove it later).

CSS:

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form{
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.form__actions{
  text-align: center;
}
.form__button{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #3498db;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-appereance: none;
  -moz-appereance: none;
  -ms-appereance: none;
  appereance: none;  
}
.form__row{
  margin: 0 -10px;
}
.form__row:before, .form__row:after{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.form__field{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.form__field:nth-child(2n-1){
  width: 50%;
}
.form__field:nth-child(2n){
  width: 50%;
}
.form__field:nth-child(3n){
  width: 100%;
}
.form__field:hover .form__removeField{
  opacity: 1;
}
.form__removeField{
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;

  -webkit-transition(all .4s ease);
  -moz-transition(all .4s ease);
  -ms-transition(all .4s ease);
  transition(all .4s ease);
}
.form__input{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 32px; 
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-appereance: none;
  -moz-appereance: none;
  -ms-appereance: none;
  appereance: none;
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var count           = $(".input_fields_wrap").find('.form__field').length; //or write a static number if you know how many fields you will have

  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click

    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(count < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      count++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div type="text" class="form__field"><input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="'+count+'"><div class="form__removeField remove_field">x</div></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
    count--;
  })
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="form__actions">
    <button class="form__button add_field_button">Add input</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form__row input_fields_wrap">
    <div type="text" class="form__field">
      <input type="text" class="form__input">
      <div class="form__removeField remove_field">x</div>
    </div>
    <div type="text" class="form__field">
      <input type="text" class="form__input">
      <div class="form__removeField remove_field">x</div>
    </div>
    <div type="text" class="form__field">
      <input type="text" class="form__input">
      <div class="form__removeField remove_field">x</div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</form>
```

Hopefilly, I understood the logic behind your input creation/removal.

Comment: Thanks...that is what i need....but i see that i describe one thing wrong..so if you can update code with small modification....i forget to describe that you need to have two boxes in row...so if we have 3 boxes (first row: 2boxes each 100px; and second row: 1box...200px if we have 4 boxes (first row: 2boxes each 100px; second row: 2boxes each 100px;....if you have 5boxes (first row: 2boxes each 100px;...second row: 2boxes each 100px; and third row one box width: 200px;) If i im not clear about detail description please replay then i will draw in paint example.

Comment: In css part change ".form__field:nth-child(3n){
  width: 100%;
}" for ".form__field:last-child:nth-child(2n-1){
  width: 100%;
}"